# Display the total registered users

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show on my page the total Registered Users. I am using this:

```
<?php
//connect to db
require_once('connect.php');

$usrcnt = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM members");
$res = mysql_num_rows($usrcnt);

$cnt_mbrs = mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
```

And then I call `$cnt_mbrs` in my page but I get errors like:

> mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource...

Is it correct what I am doing?

Comment: You do not need to add DISTINCT if ID is a primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$usrcnt = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM members");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($usrcnt);
$cnt_mbrs = $res ['cnt']
```

Is more correct.

Comment: I changed the alias & reference to make it more obvious what is being referred to.

Comment: @Crack So COUNT(*) is faster than COUNT(1) or is it same?

Comment: @Crack Thanks. I'll use * in that case :)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_num_rows` returns the number of rows in the result set. Change to

```
$cnt_mbrs = mysql_fetch_array($usercnt);
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps for performance considerations it might be better to just keep a running total.

*Yes I know that the database will not be normalised*

Comment: I was just thinking that the adopted method is not right as each page that requires the number of registered users will have to do a count. Not sure of the indexes etc involved. Just appears to be over-enginnered IMHO.